# Shopware 6: CLI command to create admin user not working

Tags: command-line-interface, admin, shopware

I am trying below CLI command , but its not working -

[image]

**[EDIT]**

```
$ php bin/console sw:admin:create --email=amitgame20023@gmail.com --username=amit --name=Amit --locale=en --password=tima@321 --no-interaction


  There are no commands defined in the "sw:admin" namespace.  

  Did you mean one of these?                                  
      swiftmailer                                             
      swiftmailer:email                                       
      swiftmailer:spool
```

The above error is coming while I am trying to add new admin user.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please share your errors in text form - additionally provide your attempts to resolve these errors

Comment: I tried to create a new admin user using CLI command , but its showing above error

Comment: And what makes you think that this should work? How is this even related to programming?

Comment: The documentation by shopware , has provided details on it - https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/tutorials-and-faq/reset-the-backend-password?category=shopware-5-en/tutorials-and-faq, I do think that someone has face this issue.

Comment: As you can see in the upper right section, that's the documentation for Shopware 5, not for Shopware 6

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase, I got that, but I was looking for CLI command to do this.

Comment: Probably, you should ask Shopware to provide such a command in their latest version, if it does not yet. After all, this is not related to programming

Comment: Yes, you are right , and thanks

Comment: sw:user:create @amit_game

Answer (score 1):

The shopware command user:create might yield what you are looking for:

```
user:create [-a|--admin] [-p|--password PASSWORD] [--firstName FIRSTNAME] [--lastName LASTNAME] [--email EMAIL] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <username>
```

Comment: sw user:create -a -p test --email test@example.com testAdmin works for me

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using the installer?

Please take a look here: https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/erste-schritte/shopware-6-installieren

or here:
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/first-steps/installing-shopware-6